# Long melt output, select for boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, melt

I have a large melt output - 4608940, 2, comprising 1000 columns with ca. 4000+ rows.  The variable column entries do not have the same number of points.

Is there a way to select certain data within the melt to use with ggplot2/boxplot()?  Say column 50, column 130, col 650?

Easily done using r's base boxplot() and the original data.

Comment: One can always select columns in R using `dat[,c(50,130,650)]` or `subset(dat, select=c(50,130,650))` or `dplyr::select(dat, c(50,130,650))`.

Comment: If you are feeding the entire data to `ggplot2` but only want the boxplot layer to use specific columns, then `geom_boxplot(data = ~ subset(., select=c(50,130,650)))` might work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Get some data (1000 columns, 4000 rows)
df<-data.table(sapply(seq(1,1000), function(x) rnorm(4000)))

# Melt the data (result is 4,000,000 x 2)
plot_input = melt(df, id.vars =NULL, measure.vars=colnames(df), variable.name = "col_num", value.name = "value")

# boxplots of selected columns
ggplot(
    plot_input[col_num %in% c("V50", "V130", "V650")],
    aes(y=value, x=col_num, color=col_num)) + 
geom_boxplot() + 
theme(legend.position="none") + labs(x="Column", y="Value")
```

[boxplots of selected columns from melt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUMQi.png)

Comment: r2evans, langtang - thank you very much for sharing your insights and understanding.

Comment: Hi @langtang, I am getting an unusual error - I ran your answer exactly as you gave it , it worked perfectly.  Over the last few days the following error has  arisen `-Error in col_num %in% c("V50", "V130", "V650") : 
  object 'col_num' not found.  ` My R has not updated, I have not made any changes to your answer.  Any idea as to what has happened?Thx

Comment: I have just ran your answer on a windows machine, it works perfectly.  So it must be a Mac issue.  V strange

Comment: @Screamh you don't have to melt the entire frame either. For example, you can select the columns you want prior to the melt like this: `plot_input = melt(df[,.(V50,V130,V650)], id.vars =NULL, measure.vars=NULL, variable.name = "col_num", value.name = "value")`

Comment: Thx langtang, am still v new to r, and didn't know this.  Much appreciated.